# jQuery UI Sortable doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have this rows of div that I want sort as I want, I tried it but it doesn't move !

```js
$("#sortable").sortable({
    cancel: ".fixed"
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sortable" class="row">
    <div id="sortable" style="margin-bottom:20px; cursor: move;">1</div>
    <div id="sortable" style="margin-bottom:20px; cursor: move;">2</div>
    <div id="sortable" style="margin-bottom:20px; cursor: move;">3</div>
    <div id="sortable" style="margin-bottom:20px; cursor: move;">4</div>
    <div id="sortable" style="margin-bottom:20px; cursor: move;">5</div>
</div>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kT4PV/1/).

Comment: worth noting that the console is showing : " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's time to upgrade plugins or use relevant jQuery version as `1.7.2`:

http://jsfiddle.net/kT4PV/2/

You should be interested in using jQuery migrate: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/